# Returning specific Group By Criteria from a Select Statement Inside of a Where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select numeric_value
from table
where numeric_value >
(select avg(numeric_value)
from table
group by id)
```

Since this where clause returns multiple values It is unable to execute. I am attempting to return only one value... to illustrate, would return under the conditions that if e.numeric_value > d.avg(numeric_value) and also e.id = d.id. This is in oracle DB.

Comment: The outer query does not use ID at all... I don't get what you are trying to obtain. Could you add examples,please?

Comment: Try an `EXISTS` clause subquery instead to use two conditions.  That said, I wouldn't expect this to return one result either way.

Comment: To try and clarify, I want to get the numeric_values that are greater than the average of numeric_values grouped by their ids. Each numeric_value will have an id and I want to add those that have matching id's and then return the numeric_values that are greater than the average of those with matching ids. So if 2 4 6 are my values and their id's are 1 2 1. I would expect to return 6 and 1. since 6 > avg(2,6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So if 2 4 6 are my values and their id's are 1 2 1. I would expect to return 6 and 1. since 6 > avg(2,6)

You could use correlated subquery:

```
select numeric_value
from table t1
where numeric_value >(select avg(numeric_value)
                      from table t2
                      WHERE t1.id = t2.id);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=228c2c8335434c12bbb0a58710f65228)**

Note: Your design looks somehow wrong, id should be unique (or it is just labeled incorrectly as id).